# Implementing SCD Type 2 using Pentaho Kettle (Pentaho Data Integeration 5.2)

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, pentaho-cde

I am having a table, plan, with columns `p_id,p_name,start_date,end_date,last_updated`

Problem Statement: when a customer changes from plan A to plan B, its end_date corresponding to plan A gets updated in the table and at the same time a new record for plan B inserted into the table.

I am creating a data warehouse in which "plan" is one of my dimension. Now, for customer A, i want to maintain his plan history in the dimension table. I know, we can solve this problem using SCD Type 2 dimension table. I am using **Pentaho Data Integeration tool 5.2**. I am trying to solve this problem using "**dimension lookup/update**" feature available in the tool. But the problem is that I want to insert values for "start_date" and "end_date" from my plan table, not what is set in the "dimension lookup/update". So whenever, a customer changes its plan, its end_date should be updated in the dimension table and at the same time a new record for plan B should be inserted in the table for the same customer.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to solve this problem i.e. values for start_date and end_date should get updated in the dimension table which are coming from my plan table not what pentaho kettle degenerates?

Comment: Could you explain your source and target (DWH) data more, please? Otherwise, your goal is not 100% clear for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the UPDATE step. This will give you the flexibility of updating any columns with the values/fields you like.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion....but one question...can we achieve SCD Type 2 Dimension table with this tool? Also, is it possible to maintain versioning of record with this tool?

Comment: Yes it is! That's what the dimension lookup/update step does. See: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Dimension+Lookup-Update

Answer (score 2):

Using the Dimension Lookup/Update step you can specify a date field as the timestamp to delimit versions. If you don't, it'll use the current timestamp.

Example: a record has a set of attributes and a specific timestamp, lets call it update_date from which the new record is valid.

Fill in the dimension lookup/update step as usual, with the attributes you want to track as "Insert" on the update type, but on the stream datefield type the update?date field name. The previous version will use that value as the date_to, whereas the new version will use it as date_from.